# iptables slows down outgoing web request

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

Before I enabled iptables, requests via curl to [this url](http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=) were instant. But after configuring iptables it takes almost 30-40 seconds to get response. How do I make particular url white listed so it can be retrieved instantly like before iptables?

Comment: You would need to show us the rules you configured.

Answer (score 1):

With a quick on the given url (http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=), it's just a simple web display and nothing related to heavy any logic, and then, the problem is most likely to be a problem on the DNS resolving delay once enabling the iptables within your system.

In the most case, the DNS lookup should be fast and sub-second action, but it usually enlarged once the DNS server is unreachable and need to try the second one.

In your case, it looks everything is working fine beforehand so we can assume there is not configuration issue for your web query w/ Curl.

So, it's suggest to try the following:

1. ping the host (api.hostip.info) from your server before and after the iptables enabling to see any difference.
2. Try to use the IP 162.220.62.158 (api.hostip.info) instead when running the Curl query and see is the case improved.

If the above problem is confirmed, you can come back to your fw rule and see anything one affecting the nameserver in your resolve.conf file and try to eliminate it.